# Complexity of List concatentation( ::: ) in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, queue, concatenation, immutability

I am reading Martin Odersky's Scala book and have come accross an example I just do not understand.
So basically he is explaining how to implement an immutable queue data structure, that is backed by an immutable list.
This is the code:

```
class SlowAppendQueue[T](elems: List[T]) {
  def head = elems.head
  def tail = new SlowAppendQueue(elems.tail)
  def enqueue(x: T) = new SlowAppendQueue(elems ::: List(x))
}
```

He mentions that enqueue is an O(n) operation, as it takes time proptional to the number of elements in the queue.

But why is the case? Is enqueue not just a matter of making the last element of the new List(x), which is also the first element as it has only one element, point to the head of elems? Which is an O(1) operation...

Any help on clearing this up would be great thanks!

Comment: See http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html; Note that `List()` is _immutable_, so you cannot change the last element without changing the whole List.

Answer (score 3):

In a [singly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list) every element has a pointer to it's next element. When you have a List[A] you effectively have a pointer only to the head of the list. So, in order to find the last element(with no pointer, where you'll concatenate other list) you must traverse the whole list.

An aside:
You may ask why there is no *immutable* [doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Doubly_linked_list), and the answer is pretty simple: you can't create element A1 without creating A2 and vice versa(because they need to have pointers to each other). You would have to manually insert it, thus it's mutable...

Answer (score 0):

> He mentions that enqueue is an O(n) operation, as it takes time proptional to the number of elements in the queue.

A `List` is an immutable data structure in Scala. As such, when you add an element, you're creating a new `List` with the new element. Also, Scala's concrete implementation for `List[T]` is Cons `::`, which is implemented as a `head`, containing the first element, and a `tail` containing all elements other than `head`.

A Queue is a data structure with FIFO (first in first out) semantics. This means that if you implement it with a `List`, as the example is doing in the naive approach, you'd have the cost of needing to *append* the element to the end of the list, which is an O(n) operation where n is the number of elements in the list.

On the contrary, *prepending* an element to a `List[T]` is a constant time operation, requiring only to create a new list where the new element is the head, and the current list prior to the prepending is the tail. This is done using `Cons` (::)